# Qt: Attempting to initialize a layout in mainwindow with mainwindow causes error when given 'this' as parent?

Tags: c++, qt

So I'm trying to understand why this output would occur when initializing a layout in the basic mainwindow generated in qt.

`QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already has a layout`

The code that causes this is:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , topHLayout(new QHBoxLayout)
    , middleHlayout(new QHBoxLayout(this))
```

topHlayout causes no error but am not specifying a parent however middleHlayout does when giving the mainWindow as its parent.  From my assumption I can't add a layout to a widget?  This makes it confusing ass to how would one create new windows with layouts in them.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: QMainWindow class has its own layout preinstalled for convenience (for placing menus, status bar, tool bars, etc).  You should add you layouts and child widgets to the widget returned by its centralWidget() method instead.

Comment: Thank you!! Its taking me awhile to learn Qt